# receiving integers in Assembly

Tags: function, assembly, x86, parameter-passing, masm

*The AddTwo procedure receives two integers and returns their sum in EAX.

```
AddTwo PROC,
  val1:DWORD, val2:DWORD

  mov eax,val1
  add eax,val2
  ret
AddTwo ENDP
```

How do val1 and val2 get passed integer values? Do they come from the stack, if so how are they being taken exactly? What does the function call to this look like?

Comment: the caller needs to pass them in

Comment: Function call looks like `push eax` \ `push ebx` \ `call AddTwo`. Maybe `add sp, 8` after if the function does not clean the stack. `proc` expands to `push bp` \ `mov bp, sp` and then `val1` and `val2` expand to `dword [bp + 4]` or `dword [bp + 8]`, and the `ret` expands to (perhaps first `mov sp, bp` then) `pop bp` and `retn` (or `retn 8`). Or if you're programming in a 32-bit segment then it uses `ebp` and `esp` and the stack offsets from `ebp` are `+ 8` and `+ 12`.

Comment: @ecm: The use of EAX makes 32-bit code a good guess.  Note that MASM syntax would be `dword ptr`, not just dword.  Anyway, yeah, assembling this and then looking at disassembly would show how MASM's magic turns into actual code, although I think that syntax only works for stack args, not for example for `__fastcall` so hopefully you couldn't have `val1` expanding to `ecx`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Yeah I didn't include the `ptr` because I just put in whatever the NASM syntax is. Don't think MASM recognises `retn` either. And yeah the use of `eax` certainly means a 386 is required but it's unclear whether this is in a 32-bit default operand size segment or a 16-bit one. I think `proc` can be used for either 16/32 bits, far/near call, stack parameter order either forwards/backwards, and either function cleans stack / caller cleans stack.

Comment: @ecm: Right, I'm pretty sure `proc` works for either mode, but since 16-bit mode is even more thoroughly obsolete than 32-bit mode, I would have assumed 32-bit unless indicated otherwise.  (Because declaring args for `proc` *doesn't* work in 64-bit MASM, IIRC from other SO Q&As.  Probably not with any register-arg calling convention.)  And yeah, either order is possible, so yeah looking with a disassembler will show you where it's looking for which one, and thus how to call it.  The lack of `proc near` or `proc far` I think means it's near, or maybe just the default which can be set elsewhere.